# rearranging panels in lattice xyplot

Tags: r, panel, lattice

Below is the code that I was using when I only conditioned on a single variable. Using index.cond as below worked for switching the order of the panels in the final graph. However, now that I am conditioning on two variables the below code does not work to switch positions of the different panels. How do I modify index.cond to work? Here is my code and below is a picture of the graph and sample data:

```
libs <- c('lattice', 'latticeExtra', 'gridExtra', 'MASS', 'colorspace', 'plyr', 'Hmisc', 'scales')
lapply(libs, require, character.only = T)


conversion_test <- read.table("Desktop/FAST/convert_test/Results/fasconvert_Results", sep="\t",   header=TRUE)


scatter.lattice <- xyplot(Time.to.Completion..s. ~ Number.of.Sequences | Length * Conversion, data  = conversion_test, ylab = "Time to Completion (s)", xlab = "Number of Sequences", index.cond=list(c(2,1,4,3)), pch=16, 
                         panel = function(x, y, ...) {
                         panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
                         lm1 <- lm(y ~ x)
                         lm1sum <- summary(lm1)
                         r2 <- lm1sum$adj.r.squared
                         panel.abline(a = lm1$coefficients[1], 
                                      b = lm1$coefficients[2])
                         panel.text(labels = 
                                      bquote(italic(R)^2 == 
                                               .(format(r2, 
                                                        digits = 5))),
                                    x = 500000, y = 10)
                         },
                       xscale.components = xscale.components.subticks,
                       yscale.components = yscale.components.subticks,
                       as.table = TRUE)
scatter.lattice
```

I would like to switch the order of the columns.
[image: Output]

Here is an example dataset:

```
Numberofseq timetoCompletion Length Conversion
25000         9.3             100bp    ClustalW
250000        45              100bp    ClustalW
25000         9.3             100bp    Fasta
250000        45              100bp    Fasta
25000         9.3             1000bp    ClustalW
250000        45              1000bp    ClustalW
25000         9.3             1000bp    Fasta
250000        45              1000bp    Fasta
```

Comment: Switch the order how exactly? What is the desired output?

Comment: I would like to switch the order of the columns. To be more explicit numbering left to right, top to bottom of the above figure I want the order to be 2,1,4,3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `?xyplot` help page, under `index.cond`,

> If index.cond is a list, it has to be as long as the number of conditioning variables, and the i-th component has to be a valid indexing vector for levels(g_i), where g_i is the i-th conditioning variable in the plot

So since you have two conditioning variables, you should have a list of length two. Each of your variables has two levels. I still don't understand how you are numbering these plots, but depending on how your factors are leveled, try some form of

```
index.cond = list(2:1, 2:1)
#or
index.cond = list(2:1, 1:2)
```

but using this along with `as.table` seems a bit odd.

Comment: I am just now learning R to create plots for publication because of this I am mostly copying code. I will remove as.table.

Comment: the default layout in a lattice  display counts rows from the bottom up. To have a display from the top down use `lattice.options(default.args = list(as.table = TRUE))`